# Can I transform the embedded interactivity coordinate system result from lat lon to epsg 3857 (web mercator)?

Tags: mapbox

When using the embedded interactivity embedded interactivity function on the iOS SDK I can click a map tile and get the data coords in LAT LON  but I would like to have the result in EPSG 3857 WGS 84...is this possible?  If so what is the transform command?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I am going to answer my own question.  I could not find a transform function.  So I passed the LAT LONG coordinate pair to the webservice and did the transformation on the server.

Comment: Which webservice did you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Leaflet/Mapbox.

Here's an example

```
var latlng = L.latLng(45, -120);
var sphericalMercator = L.Projection.SphericalMercator.project(latlng);
```

`sperhicalMercator.x` => -2.0943951023931953

`sphericalMercator.y` => 0.8813735870195429

You'll still need to multiply these coordinates by 6378137 (earth's radius in meters) (why Leaflet doesn't do this, I don't know...), and you get the spherical mercator equivalent to the original lat/long (45, -120):

(-13358338.8952, 5621521.48619)